# Angular: Reuse reducer and selectors in different roots (not using redux)

Tags: angular, store, ngrx, ngrx-reducers

I do have different routes

/department

/candidates

/candidates-department

I have to use the same reducer structure (state and action) in /candidates and /candidates-department. The candidate part is common with minor difference in fetching data from api and having that data in store.

so /candidates will list all candidates, but for /candidates-department we do have department list that shows candidates corresponding to that department.

Is there any way I can use the same store/action/reducer from /candidates in /candidates-department with only difference in feature key in both /candidates and /candidates-department.

I need to reuse selectors as well.

Answer (score 0):

ngrx provides a single storage for a single `StoreModule.forRoot`. All its children will use the same store.

If you want to achieve desired behavior you need to change the structure of your app so that `StoreModule.forRoot` is called in a child module that belongs to the rote.

If you need to call `StoreModule.forRoot` in `AppModule` due to other dependencies, then bad news, there's no way to split contexts for child modules of a parent with `StoreModule.forRoot`.

If you need it - try to add to your actions a property that points to a key. And then respect this key in reducers and selectors. It requires more coding, but that's the only way to split it currently.